# Sticky Sidebar issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using stickySidebar.js for my sidebar. The problem I recently discovered with it, is as you can see on the image below, it pops up above the `#container` in Internet Explorer, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari (MAC) and the iPad.

I am guessing it has something to do with the `positioning: ;`, but I can't figure out whats wrong with it for sure, maybe the script is altering the positioning.

What I also found out, is that if you extend the browser window full screen, the `#sidebar` appears like it should, on top of the container. But if you shrink the browser window and reload. `#sidebar` appears on above the container, like in the image below. Same goes for JSFiddle, if you shrink the window it appears above, and if you extend it, it appears like it should on top.

I've made a fully functioning **[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ey5re/13/)**.

[image]

**And my CSS:**

```
 #sidebar {
    display: block; margin: 0 0 0 80px; padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    width: 290px; height: 300px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#sidebar.sticky { float: none; position: fixed; top: auto; z-index: 10; left: auto; }

    div#container {
        position: relative; float: left; clear: none;
        display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 2000px;

        background-color: yellow;
    }

    footer {
        position: relative; float: left; clear: none;
        display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 500px;

        background-color: #1a3c58;
    }
```

**If I change `#sidebar.sticky` position from `fixed` to `absolute`. The script doesn't work.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line from the `config` variable:

```
sidebarTopMargin: -10,
```

That seems to be what you don't want.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've probably misunderstood the issue. I couldn't see anything else wrong with the demo.